Percentages values in Azure DevOps dashboards
How can I bring in percentage on one side of the chart(shown below) in Azure DevOps dashboards and not just numbers or count. Currently it seems there is a limitation to have percentage under queries or test plans.
What is the solution to bring percentages either using any out of the box solution or any API or any extensions?

